# Where does Visual Studio store the templates used when doing right-click? For unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, mstest, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to change the unit test files that get created when using right-click in Visual Studio. I'm sure the documentation exists somewhere about where you do this, but I've been unsuccessful in my search.

Note: there are a couple of ways that Visual Studio can auto-generate unit tests.

First Way: 
I create a unit test project. Right-click in the project, select add -> unit test, which creates a file like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest2
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
    }
}
```

Second way: While in an existing class file (not the test project), select a method, right-click Create Unit Tests, which produces a file with code that resembles this

```
[TestClass()]
public class UnitTest2
{
    [TestMethod()]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Assert.Fail();
    }
}
```

I want to use the second way, but I prefer the code generated by the first way (without the unnecessary `()`). I believe that Visual Studio contains template files that you can edit for such tasks, but I've never done that. I looked in `C:\Users\<myusername>\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual` C# but there are no files in that folder.

Comment: I found this and followed it to find the UnitTest.cs file for new UnitTestProject https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-locate-and-organize-project-and-item-templates?view=vs-2019

Comment: That does not appear to be the file used by what I describe as "Second Way" above.

Answer (score 1):

Reference [How to: Locate and organize project and item templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-locate-and-organize-project-and-item-templates?view=vs-2019)

I was able to find the item templates *(right click explorer -> Add -> UnitTest)* following the format provided by the documentation linked above

```
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\<edition>\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\<Language>\<Locale ID>
```

which for me when looking for the Test item templates worked out to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Test\1033
```

as I am currently on Community 2017 and documentation targets 2019

In that folder I found 4 folders

```
BasicUnitTest
GenericTest
OrderedTest
SimpleUnitTest
```

each containing their respective templates

For example *BasicUnitTest/UnitTest.cs*

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    [TestClass]
    public class $safeitemname$
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Similar was found for the unit test project template in the *ProjectTemplates* folder

Comment: That appears to be the template used to create a new test project from within a project. What I'm looking for, though, is the template that creates a unit test file when you right-click within a project and select Create Unit Tests. Wherever that file is located, it generates different code in the class and method attributes: [TestClass()] instead of [TestClass].

Answer (score 1):

It is not what you are looking for but as an alternative you can use [Unit Test Boilerplate Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RandomEngy.UnitTestBoilerplateGenerator) visual studio extension to generate whatever boilerplate test code you need.